# What is the default caching behaviour for Firebase Hosting with Cloud Run?

Tags: firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have an HTTP service running in Cloud Run that I have mapped to Firebase Hosting using a wildcard to send all routes to the service.

```
// firebase.json

{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "mysite",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/**",
          "run": {
            "serviceId": "myservice",
            "region": "europe-west2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update: I've also tried `"source": "**"` and config with or without the default static hosting using `"public": "public"` and the result is the same. The CDN appears to cache all content from Cloud Run by default.**

The documentation for Firebase Hosting says: (bold my emphasis)

> Any requested static content is automatically cached on the CDN. If you redeploy your site's content, Firebase Hosting automatically clears all your cached static content across the CDN until the next request.

> However, because Cloud Functions and Cloud Run services generate content dynamically, the content for a given URL can vary based on such things as user input or the user's identity. To account for this, **requests that are handled by backend code do not cache on the CDN by default**.

However, within the browser developer Network tab I see cache hits (screenshot below):

[image]

Note the `server: Google Frontend` with `x-cache: Hit` indicating that the CDN served the content. I can confirm there are no Cloud Run logs for subsequent HTTP GET requests.

I've seen other articles online (one on medium) that says the opposite, that by default caching is enabled.

Is the Google documentation currently up to date? If so, what have I missed? I should mention that my HTTP service uses `__session` cookies for some routes. The example above was before any signin took place, so no cookies were sent from the browser.

I've also tested this using curl and I also get the same result:

```
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: myhost
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< server: Google Frontend
< x-country-code: GB
< accept-ranges: bytes
< date: Mon, 04 Oct 2021 13:17:19 GMT
< x-served-by: cache-lhr7335-LHR
< x-cache: HIT
< x-cache-hits: 1
< x-timer: S1633353439.260200,VS0,VE1
< vary: x-fh-requested-host, accept-encoding
< content-length: 11949
<
```

**Hello world example**

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "os"
        "time"
)

func main() {
    log.Print("starting server...")
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
        log.Printf("defaulting to port %s", port)
    }

    // Start HTTP server.
    log.Printf("listening on port %s", port)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "The time now is %s\n", time.Now())
}
```

```
FROM golang:1.17.1-alpine as builder

LABEL stage=builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go build .


FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add tzdata

RUN mkdir -p /app/bin

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/helloworld ./bin

CMD ["/app/bin/helloworld"]
```

firebase.json

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "run": {
        "serviceId": "helloworld"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Curl output

1. CALLING CLOUD RUN DIRECTLY

```
andy@oak:~/projects/test-to-be-removed/public$ curl -v https://helloworld-q2ftkxvbva-uc.a.run.app/
*   Trying 216.239.36.53:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to helloworld-q2ftkxvbva-uc.a.run.app (216.239.36.53) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.a.run.app
*  start date: Sep 13 01:08:45 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 20 01:08:44 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "helloworld-q2ftkxvbva-uc.a.run.app" matched cert's "*.a.run.app"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1C3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55718a90ae10)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: helloworld-q2ftkxvbva-uc.a.run.app
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< x-cloud-trace-context: 4844f53bed45b95ba5c11f3873217904;o=1
< date: Mon, 04 Oct 2021 15:31:40 GMT
< server: Google Frontend
< content-length: 74
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
< 
The time now is 2021-10-04 15:31:40.017735277 +0000 UTC m=+1034.166310273
* Connection #0 to host helloworld-q2ftkxvbva-uc.a.run.app left intact
```

2. CALLING CLOUD RUN VIA FIREBASE HOSTING (1st time Cache MISS)

```
andy@oak:~/projects/test-to-be-removed/public$ curl -v https://test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app/helloworld
*   Trying 199.36.158.100:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app (199.36.158.100) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=web.app
*  start date: Sep 20 20:09:34 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 19 20:09:33 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app" matched cert's "*.web.app"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1D4
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55ca2e032e10)
> GET /helloworld HTTP/2
> Host: test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< server: Google Frontend
< x-cloud-trace-context: b62eb4e97a7e8dbd22b1958616455f27;o=1
< x-country-code: GB
< accept-ranges: bytes
< date: Mon, 04 Oct 2021 15:32:12 GMT
< x-served-by: cache-lhr7331-LHR
< x-cache: MISS
< x-cache-hits: 0
< x-timer: S1633361532.898050,VS0,VE234
< vary: x-fh-requested-host, accept-encoding
< content-length: 73
< 
The time now is 2021-10-04 15:32:12.06951937 +0000 UTC m=+1066.218094364
* Connection #0 to host test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app left intact
```

3. CALLING CLOUD RUN VIA FIREBASE HOSTING (2nd time unexpected Cache HIT)

```
andy@oak:~/projects/test-to-be-removed/public$ curl -v https://test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app/helloworld
*   Trying 199.36.158.100:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app (199.36.158.100) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=web.app
*  start date: Sep 20 20:09:34 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 19 20:09:33 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app" matched cert's "*.web.app"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1D4
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x562f5255ae10)
> GET /helloworld HTTP/2
> Host: test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< server: Google Frontend
< x-cloud-trace-context: b62eb4e97a7e8dbd22b1958616455f27;o=1
< x-country-code: GB
< accept-ranges: bytes
< date: Mon, 04 Oct 2021 15:32:14 GMT
< x-served-by: cache-lhr7371-LHR
< x-cache: HIT
< x-cache-hits: 1
< x-timer: S1633361534.332609,VS0,VE1
< vary: x-fh-requested-host, accept-encoding
< content-length: 73
< 
The time now is 2021-10-04 15:32:12.06951937 +0000 UTC m=+1066.218094364
* Connection #0 to host test-to-be-removed-c02e2.web.app left intact
```

Comment: The problem with the caching could be due to the browser. Please check the [following article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-hosting-and-cloud-run-cache-38afa6bd4beb) if it helps you.

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty This problem also occurs when using curl requests so isn't only browser related.

Comment: Can you please provide logs?